# how do you change the tooltip value on an img in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am installing an application that has html properties as this:

```
<img class="logo-icon ng-scope" src="img/fav32.png" bs-tooltip="'Default'" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="" title="">
```

I need to change the bs-tooltip value, I tried changing it but not working. The application may be caching somewhere.

Is there a way to change the value of bs-tooltip by css, or javascript?

I tried to change bs-tooltip value from Default Basic as this:

```
<img class="logo-icon" src="img/fav32.png" bs-tooltip="'Basic'" data-placement="bottom">
```

did not work.

Comment: How have you tried to change the value?

Comment: @JensW, yes, I tried that it is not working for some reason. would there be a way to force overriding that?

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: In case you are using angular-strap this could help: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/1.0/#/tooltip Otherwise you have other working answers now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it via Javascript :

```
var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
image.setAttribute("bs-tooltip", "your new value");
```

Or, if you're using jQuery :

```
$("img").attr("bs-tooltip", "your new value");
```

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hsxx0pwo/

You can target your image more precisely by giving it an `id` and using `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 0):

### Use the native .setAttribute() method

```
document.getElementsByClassName('logo-icon')[0].setAttribute('bs-tooltip', "'Basic'");
```

*Note: `.getElementsByClassName()` is not supported in IE8 and earlier.*

### jQuery alternative

If you have jQuery available:

```
$(".logo-icon").attr("bs-tooltip", "'Basic'");
```